# How to call a php function in psysh console?

Tags: php

Sorry, pretty noob to psysh.

Basically I have this function in my psysh/php:

```
>>> show $newcsr

  class Tokyo {
      private function sign($caCert,$userCsr) {
           $caKey = file_get_contents('/home/nairobi/ca.key');
           $userCert = openssl_csr_sign($userCsr, $caCert, $caKey, 365, ['digest_alg'=>'sha256']);
           openssl_x509_export($userCert, $userCertOut);
           return $userCertOut;
      }
   }
```

How do I call sign function to generate me a certificate in psysh console?

Comment: Since your function is declared as private, you can't call it from outside the Tokyo class. If you declare it as public, you can instanciate an object of the Tokyo class and call the function: `$tokyo = new Tokyo(); $tokyo->sign(..., ...);`

Answer (score 0):

Psysh provides a `sudo` command for bypassing visibility restrictions, so you can do: `sudo $newcsr->sign($caCert,$userCsr);`